# How to use HTML::form to upload file in Cordova Webview?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm struggling using CordovaWebview to upload a file.

And I'm following the example [here](https://github.com/claudemamo/file-attach-cordova-upload-jqm). It is like this

```
<form id="file-attachment-form" action="http://192.168.1.100/web/app.php/api/rest/users/264372155.json">

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="attachment">Attachment:</label>
            <input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment"/>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

and the js is like this, actually it's not as important.

```
$('#file-attachment-form').submit(function () {

        formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:$('#file-attachment-form').attr('action'),
            data:formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            error:function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Failed to upload file')
            },
            success:function () {
                alert('File uploaded')
            }
        })
```

The problem comes when I attach a file into the form.

I click on the "file" button and select a file, then click OK, it crashes.

But it works fine in android native webbrowser. So I think the problem is in the action of selecting the file from Android native filebrowser.

And idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps using a modern Android (e.g., 4.4)? Because [Issue 62220](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220) has caused a major regression in file uploading with webviews. You can work around the issue by using a [cordova plugin to open the file picker dialog using native code](https://github.com/cdibened/filechooser).